# Conditional Formatting of interdependent values in one cell Excel

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I am working on a spreadsheet for planning road improvements, there are two aspects. Resurfacing and Surface Dressing these are interdependent values as you can see in the example below. However there is no scenario where both numbers can exceed 100 and I was hoping of finding a way of displaying total percentages of resurfacing and surface dressing in one cell. Ideally with resurfacing on the left of the cell and surface dressing on the right.

Currently I am using conditional formatting on each cell, I know I can store two values in one cell but it doesn't seem possible to use conditional formatting on these cells.

Any Ideas how this can be achieved? Would be much appreciated

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure which values are which, but combining two results into one cell can be done like this:

```
="A438 "&A4&" "&A5
```

and you could replace the A438 with a cell reference :

```
=A2&" "&A4&" "&A5
```

Comment: Ah should have stated it's the two percentages I'm trying to place in one column

Comment: Should still work, just change A4 and A5 to the cells you want to use... If you want to add formatting then: ="A438 "&A4&"&"&" "&A5&"&" for example

Comment: thanks for the advice however I can't seem to get conditional formatting working on this, I've tried to clarify my question a little by editing the above,

Comment: I don't know how you could apply conditional formatting to two parts or numbers in one cell, perhaps someone else does.